# How to get images to show on next.js?

Tags: next.js

I am new to next.js, I understand that the next.js is javascript that mixes the HTML and JS.

I am trying to add an image but its not working, and I am not sure why, I do get an error that appears on the webrowser.

next.js

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'

export default function Home() {

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
      </Head>

      <div className={styles.scrollContainer}>
        <Image src="../images/Scroll.png" alt="Scroll Image" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Error I get]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should provide image sizes or provide `layout="fill"` and import your image first:

```js
import scroll from '../images/Scroll.png';
.
.
.
<Image alt="Scroll Image" src={scroll} width={1000} height={1000} />

// or

<Image alt="Scroll Image" src={scroll} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" />
```

Comment: That worked thank you, just want to ask, every time I want to add an image am I always going to have to ```import "name" from "path"```

Comment: @Sheldon probably yes to prevent an error when you will build your app